# aws cli simulate-custom-policy newbie, basic s3 call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Am exploring the aws simulate-custom-policy.

Getting an invalid input on Policy Input List.

Error is

```
An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the SimulateCustomPolicy operation: Policy input list item 1 has invalid content
```

Command is

```
aws --profile dev-insecure iam simulate-custom-policy \
 --resource-policy file://resourcePolicy.json \
 --policy-input-list file://iamPolicy.json \
 --resource-arns arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-publiclyvisible/* \
 --action-names s3:GetObject \
 --caller-arn arn:aws:iam::<my account number>:user/jc
```

the iamPolicy.json

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's easy to run into I'm afraid (took me a while to figure it out):

The AWS CLI parameter `--policy-input-list` of the [`aws . iam . simulate-custom-policy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/simulate-custom-policy.html) action expects an array of JSON *strings*:

> A list of policy documents to include in the simulation. Each document is specified as a string containing the complete, valid JSON text of an IAM policy. [...]

This means the `iamPolicy.json` file content needs to be a) an array, and b) the JSON policies need to be escaped, as follows:

```
[
  "{  \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",  \"Statement\": [  {  \"Action\": [  \"*\"  ],  \"Resource\": [  \"*\"  ],  \"Effect\": \"Allow\"  }  ]}"
]
```